# R - Pass column names into data.table formula - difference between get and eval

Tags: r, data.table

I have names of columns of `data.table` stored in variables. I need to refer to the columns via these variables. I made the code working (example below), but I have no clue why I need to use sometimes `get()` and sometime `eval()`. Can somebody clarify this, please?

```
# generate some data
foo <- rep(1:2,each = 3)
bar <- rep(c("A","B","C"),2)
baz <- rep(1:5,2)[1:6]
df <- data.frame(foo,bar,baz)
setDT(df)

# refer to columns directly by their names
df[, "qux":=baz-baz[bar=="C"], by=foo]

# save column names into variables and call columns via these variables
var1 <- "foo"
var2 <- "bar"
var3 <- "baz"
varNew <- "qux2"

df[, eval(varNew) := get(var3) - get(var3)[get(var2) == "C"], by = get(var1)]

df
   foo bar baz qux qux2
1:   1   A   1  -2   -2
2:   1   B   2  -1   -1
3:   1   C   3   0    0
4:   2   A   4   3    3
5:   2   B   5   4    4
6:   2   C   1   0    0
```

Comment: `eval(varNew)` is returning the single string `qux2` and `get(var1)` is returning all of the values in `var1`; in this case `var1` is "foo" so `get(var1)` returns the values of what is in "foo".  In other words, in your example, `eval` is returning a single string and `get` is returning the values of each column.

Comment: you don't need to use `by=get(.)` as `by` argument accept character vector of columns

Comment: You can also in many cases sidestep this whole issue by building up the entire expression using bquote and then evaling that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This example shows the difference between how `eval` and `get` differ in function.  Using a `data.table` object is not needed to show what each does.

```
iVec     <- c(123, 456)
iVarName <- "iVec"

# Returns the contents of 'iVarName' (a string).  This happens
# to be the name of a variable but doesn't have to.
eval(iVarName)
##> [1] "iVec"

# Returns the contents of what 'iVarName' refers to (it
# refers to the variable "iVec" in this case, which
# is a variable which contains a vector of integers).
get(iVarName)
##> [1] 123 456

### #########################################
### Similar to above but where the variable
### 'iVec2' does not exist.
### #########################################
rm(iVec2)
# The variable "iVec2" does not exist.
iVarName2 <- 'iVec2'

# Returns the contents of 'iVarName2' (a string).  This is not
# the name of an existing variable in this context.
eval(iVarName2)
## [1] "iVec2"
get(iVarName2)  # Returns an error because 'iVec2' doesn't exist.
## Error in get(iVarName2) : object 'iVec2' not found
```

Since this question is more about `eval` vs. `get`, I will leave the `data.table` specifics out.  The way `data.table` handles strings and variable names is very likely answered in a different SO post.